# Intermittent network with netgear access points

Tags: wireless, access-point, netgear-prosafe

I have an issue with a Netgear network. We use the following equipment:

- Netgear WC7500 Controller
- Netgear WNDAP660
- Netgear PoE-Switches and regular Switches

The deployment is basically the following

```
WC 7500 <-> PoE <-> WNDAP
          \
           Switch <-> PoE <-> WNDAP
```

Everything uses Cat 6 Cable, so 1 Gbit/s shouldn't be the problem.

The issue is, with 3 out of 4 access points, we regularly have the problem, that the connection drops. When simply surfing, the users mostly do not notice, but when streaming video or audio, the connection to the stream is lost and the playback stops. A ping during such a phase usually looks like this:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=871 ttl=64 time=3.884 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=872 ttl=64 time=7.145 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=873 ttl=64 time=40.071 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=874 ttl=64 time=19.888 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=875 ttl=64 time=8.871 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=876 ttl=64 time=3118.215 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=877 ttl=64 time=2157.423 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=878 ttl=64 time=1195.459 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=879 ttl=64 time=233.174 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=880 ttl=64 time=7.620 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=881 ttl=64 time=8.889 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=882 ttl=64 time=7.988 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=883 ttl=64 time=3.538 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=884 ttl=64 time=2.443 ms
```

As you see, the ping is quite ok, then it increases to several seconds and drops pretty fast again to something we call "good" (<10ms isn't to worry imo). Sometimes the internet connection, when using the wireless network, is lost completly, but cable remains ok. We switched providers a few days back which din't change anything.

What we already tried:

- Change channels all the way through
- change DTIM
- decreasing RTS
- playing around with beacon time
- decreasing data rate

We have tried stuff from these resources:

- https://kb.netgear.com/23655/Troubleshooting-intermittent-wireless-or-dropped-Wi-Fi-connections
- https://community.netgear.com/t5/WiFi-Range-Extenders-Repeaters/WNDAP360-losing-connection/td-p/434686

I really have no idea, why this isn't working anymore and it bugs me quite a lot. I tried everything I know and I hope you people have an idea, what to try!

Comment: Have you looked at interference? What is your RF space in the area where the trouble access points are?

Comment: The wireless site survey that you performed before setting up the network that gave you the WAP quantity, placement, power levels, frequencies, etc. should be repeated in case of problems. It gives you a baseline from which to work as things in the wireless environment change.

Comment: RF space means exactly what? Well, there's not that much to perform. There are 10 to 15 devices using the wireless network. Each room has a single access point, the rooms are up to 250 sq ft, so nothing that access points should not cover. A heat map was created, nothing significat, signal is always good, noise less than a few percent. Personally I'm thinking more of hardware (cable) issues, but 1 of 3 failing APs are on totally different cable (different house installation circuit), so that shouldn't be the issue too...

Comment: You probably need to crank down the radio power. A wireless site survey tells you tings like that. It tells you haw many WAPs to install where, what frequencies to use for each WAP, and what power levels, etc. It is foolish to just eyball it and and hope it works right.